# Replace value table with condition in R

Tags: r, string, replace, match

I have list of dataset :

```
> data1
[1] /index.php/search?
[2] /tabel/graphic1_.php?
[3] /mod/Layout/variableView2.php?
[4] /table/tblmon-frameee.php?
```

and a table:

```
> tes
[1] http://aladdine/index.php/search?        
[2] http://aladdine/mod/params/returnParams.php 
[3] http://aladdine/mod/Layout/variableView2.php
[4] http://aladdine/index.php/bos/index?        
[5] http://aladdine/index.php/Bos
```

I want to change the value of the test table with an index on dataset which has a matching string values in the dataset. 
I have tried this code:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataset)){
  p = data[i]
  for(j in 1:length(tes)){
    t = tes [j]
    if(grepl(p, t)){
      tes[j]=i
    }
    else tes[j] = "-"
  }
}
```

My expectation result like this,

```
> tes
    [1] 1        
    [2] - 
    [3] 3
    [4] -        
    [5] -
```

But, I always get warning message `invalid factor level, NA generated`. Why?

Thanks before.

Comment: Convert everything to character.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not do exactly what you need, but effectively it should give you the same information.

```
data1<-c('/index.php/search?',
         '/tabel/graphic1_.php?',
         '/mod/Layout/variableView2.php?', 
         '/table/tblmon-frameee.php?')

tes<-c('http://aladdine/index.php/search?',        
       'http://aladdine/mod/params/returnParams.php', 
       'http://aladdine/mod/Layout/variableView2.php',
       'http://aladdine/index.php/bos/index?',        
       'http://aladdine/index.php/Bos')

> lapply(data1,FUN = function(x) which(grepl(x,tes)))

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
integer(0)
```

For example, the first output in [[1]] tells which element in "tes" match the first element in "data1" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest one as i use for loop in this code but hope this provides a solution:

```
require(data.table)

data1<-c("/index.php/search?","/tabel/graphic1_.php?","/mod/Layout/variableView2.php?","/table/tblmon-frameee.php?")


tes<-c("http://aladdine/index.php/search?","http://aladdine/mod/params/returnParams.php" ,"http://aladdine/mod/Layout/variableView2.php","http://aladdine/index.php/bos/index?","http://aladdine/index.php/Bos")
d<-data.table(d=data1,t=tes)
d$id<-seq(1:nrow(d))
for (i in 1:nrow(d))
{
d$index[i]<-lapply(data1,FUN=function(x) {ifelse(length(grep(x,tes[i]))>0,d$id[i],"-")})[i]
}
```